# Hide elements visible if a variable == true

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements

Can I have some help please ?

When I click on `.toggle-menu`, I didn't manage to hide `#overlay-menu` or `#overlay-contact` if they are `:visible` and `ovDeskVisible == false`

```
if (ovDeskVisible == false && ovMenuVisible) {
            $('#overlay-menu').hide();
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#overlay-menu').removeClass('appears');
            }, 300 );
        }
if (ovDeskVisible == false && ovContactVisible) {
            $('#overlay-contact').hide();
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#overlay-contact').removeClass('appears');
            }, 300 );
        }
```

Here my function :

```
function toggle_nav_desktop() {
    var ovDeskVisible = false;
    var ovMenuVisible = $('#overlay-menu').is(':visible');
    var ovContactVisible = $('#overlay-contact').is(':visible');

    $('.toggle-menu, .toggle-contact').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        ovDeskVisible = !ovDeskVisible;

        if ($('html').attr('lang') == 'fr-FR') {
            $('.toggle-menu h4').text($('.toggle-menu h4').text() == 'Menu' ? 'Fermer' : 'Menu');
        } else {
            $('.toggle-menu h4').text($('.toggle-menu h4').text() == 'Menu' ? 'Close' : 'Menu');
        }

        if (ovDeskVisible == true) {
            $('.icon-menu').addClass('is-opened').removeClass('is-closed');
            $('html').addClass('stop-scrolling');
            $('.circle').addClass('open appears');
        }
        if (ovDeskVisible == false) {
            $('.icon-menu').addClass('is-closed').removeClass('is-opened');
            $('html').removeClass('stop-scrolling');
            $('.circle').removeClass('open appears');
        }
    });

    $('.toggle-menu').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (ovDeskVisible == true) {
            $('#overlay-menu').show();
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#overlay-menu').addClass('appears');
            }, 300 );
        }
        if (ovDeskVisible == false && ovMenuVisible) {
            $('#overlay-menu').hide();
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#overlay-menu').removeClass('appears');
            }, 300 );
        }
        if (ovDeskVisible == false && ovContactVisible) {
            $('#overlay-contact').hide();
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#overlay-contact').removeClass('appears');
            }, 300 );
        }
    });

    $('.toggle-contact').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (ovDeskVisible == true) {
            $('#overlay-contact').show();
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#overlay-contact').addClass('appears');
            }, 300 );
        }
    });
}
```

When I click on `.toggle-menu`, how to hide `#overlay-menu` or `#overlay-contact` if they are `:visible` and `ovDeskVisible == false` ?

Comment: It looks like you have to define your question more clearly, what is it that you want, and what is not working as intended. Are you asking for a better modular way to organize your code ? Please provide a definitive question in the end, like 'Is there a way to ... ' or 'How can I do this...  '.

Comment: Edit your question and put that piece of information as part of the question. Also, try console.log to output the value of that variable, see what you get and post it as additional information. If the value of that variable ovDeskVisible is not being captured or used, mention in your question, that you are asking to know why.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help but try to change your click events from `$('.toggle-contact').click(function(e){}` to `$('.toggle-contact').on('click', function(e){}`.
Did this once and solved my problem. It worths a try.

Comment: These are equivalent. The only difference being that `.on()` allows you use `.off()`

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the rest of your code obviously, but it seems like your script should work. Are you initializing `toggle_nav_desktop()` on the document ready?

if not, try adding this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    toggle_nav_desktop();
});
```

If this doesn't help, can you create a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your HTML and everything, and share the link?

As an aside, you can simplify your statements significantly by using the not (`!`) operator, and `else` statements:

```
if (ovDeskVisible) {
    //ovDeskVisible == true
}
else {
    //ovDeskVisible == false
}

if (!ovDeskVisible && ovMenuVisible) {
    //ovDeskVisible == false
    //ovMenuVisible == true
}
else {
    //ovDeskVisible == true
    //ovMenuVisible == false
}
```